# Cordova - Ignore folders on build

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I've got a simple app for Phonegap. In the `www` folder I added some NPM sugar to help development. Now, during the build I'd like to ignore this `node_module` folder created by NPM when it loads the dependencies. It actually make the build fail.

I've added an `ant.properties` file within `root/platforms/android/` and wrote this line:

`aapt.ignore.assets:!.svn:!.git:.*:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*.scc:*~:<dir>node_*`

It prints that it ignores the folder node_modules because of that property, but when I look at the folder `root/platforms/android/assets/www` I can see the `node_modules` folder.

I guess my question is, is the folder actually being ignored in the created APK?

Comment: hey folk, i used your pattern, with a little modification (aapt.ignore.assets:<dir>node_modules) and my issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of your `APK` and change the file extension from `.apk` to `.zip` then extract the zip. You will be able to browse to the www folder and see if it's in there or not.